# Is it possible to unorder the values through listagg

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Is it possible to not to have the order by clause in the listagg function? I should do this to retain the ordering of values. I am using oracle 11g by the way. Below is the query I am using:

```
SELECT 
      wipData."Transaction Type"
      ,wipData."Details"
      ,wipData."Values"
      ,NULL
      ,wipdata.containerid
      ,wipdata.specid
      ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
      ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
      ,NULL wipdatasetupid
      ,wipdata.specname
      ,NULL linkid
FROM
(
    SELECT wipdata.containerid
          ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
          ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
          ,wipdata.specid  
          ,wipdata.specname
          ,'WIP Data Collection @'|| SUBSTR(wipdata.specname,0,4) AS "Transaction Type"
          ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatanamename ||': ' , 'break') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY wipdata.wipdatanamename) AS "Details" 
          ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatavalue, 'break') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY wipdata.wipdatanamename) AS "Values" 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT c.containerid
            ,wldd.wipdatanamename
            ,wldd.wipdatavalue
            ,wldd.iswaferdata
            ,wl.specname
            ,wl.wiplothistoryid
            ,wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
            ,wl.specid
      FROM Container C
      JOIN a_wiplothistory wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
      JOIN a_wiplotdetailshistory wld ON wl.wiplothistoryid = wld.wiplothistoryid
      JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wldd ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wldd.wiplotdetailshistoryid
      WHERE c.containername = :lotID AND wldd.iswaferdata = 0 AND wldd.servicename <> 'AdHocWIPData'
    ) wipdata
    GROUP BY wipdata.containerid
          ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
          ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
          ,wipdata.specid  
          ,wipdata.specname

) WipData

UNION ALL

SELECT 
      wipData."Transaction Type"
      ,wipData."Details"
      ,wipData."Values"
      ,NULL
      ,wipdata.containerid
      ,wipdata.specid
      ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
      ,wipdata.wiplotid
      ,NULL
      ,wipdata.specname
      ,NULL
FROM
(
SELECT wipdata.containerid
      ,wipdata.wiplotid
      ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
      ,wipdata.specid  
      ,wipdata.specname
      ,'WIP Data Collection @'|| SUBSTR(wipdata.specname,0,4) AS "Transaction Type"
      ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatanamename ||': ' || wipdata.wipdatavalue, 'break') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY wipdata.wipdatanamename) AS "Details" 
      ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatavalue, 'break') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY wipdata.wipdatanamename) AS "Values" 
FROM
(
  SELECT c.containerid
        ,wldd.wipdatanamename
        ,wldd.wipdatavalue
        ,wldd.iswaferdata
        ,wl.specname
        ,wl.wiplotid

        ,wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
        ,wl.specid
  FROM Container C
  JOIN a_wiplot wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetails wld ON wl.wiplotid = wld.wiplotid
  JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdata wldd ON wld.wiplotdetailsid = wldd.wiplotdetailsid
  WHERE c.containername = :lotID AND wldd.iswaferdata = 0 AND wldd.servicename <> 'AdHocWIPData'
) wipdata
GROUP BY wipdata.containerid
      ,wipdata.wiplotid
      ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
      ,wipdata.specid  
      ,wipdata.specname

) WipData
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: Try `(order by null)`

Comment: Hello Egor. This does not help. I'll be posting my query so you can have it viewed.

Comment: What do you mean "retain the ordering of values"? It sounds as though you want to retain the order in your table, which doesn't exist...

Comment: Try `order by dbms_random.value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retain order of values, but you **must define this order before**.

Example based on the first part of `UNION ALL` query from question:

```
SELECT 
      wipData."Transaction Type"
      ,wipData."Details"
      ,wipData."Values"
      ,NULL
      ,wipdata.containerid
      ,wipdata.specid
      ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
      ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
      ,NULL wipdatasetupid
      ,wipdata.specname
      ,NULL linkid
FROM
(
    SELECT wipdata.containerid
          ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
          ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
          ,wipdata.specid  
          ,wipdata.specname
          ,'WIP Data Collection @'|| SUBSTR(wipdata.specname,0,4) AS "Transaction Type"
          ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatanamename ||': ' , 'break') 
              --- order by row number of inner query
              WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordered_row_number) AS "Details" 
          ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatavalue, 'break') 
              --- order by row number of inner query
             WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordered_row_number) AS "Values" 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT c.containerid
            ,wldd.wipdatanamename
            ,wldd.wipdatavalue
            ,wldd.iswaferdata
            ,wl.specname
            ,wl.wiplothistoryid
            ,wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
            ,wl.specid
            ------- store number of the row in defined order ----------------- 
            , rownum as ordered_row_number
            ------------------------------------------------------------------  
      FROM Container C
      JOIN a_wiplothistory wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
      JOIN a_wiplotdetailshistory wld ON wl.wiplothistoryid = wld.wiplothistoryid
      JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wldd ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wldd.wiplotdetailshistoryid
      WHERE c.containername = :lotID AND wldd.iswaferdata = 0 AND wldd.servicename <> 'AdHocWIPData'
      ---- !!! Ordering definition mandatory to get predictable results !!! ----
      ORDER BY c.containername, wldd.servicename
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ) wipdata
    GROUP BY wipdata.containerid
          ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
          ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
          ,wipdata.specid  
          ,wipdata.specname

) WipData
```

In your case a same results as in example above can be achieved just by specifying

```
 LISTAGG(...) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.containername, wldd.servicename)
```

so there are now need for inner query modification.

If you just don't worry about the order of values in `listagg()` then use any constant in `ORDER BY` :

```
 LISTAGG(...) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY 'No order')
```

I tried to use rownum directly in listagg ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/13160)) and it works for simple queries, but also depends on execution plan, so retaining of an order of records not guaranteed.

**Update**

Same effect can be achieved with analytical function [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) :

```
SELECT 
      wipData."Transaction Type"
      ,wipData."Details"
      ,wipData."Values"
      ,NULL
      ,wipdata.containerid
      ,wipdata.specid
      ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
      ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
      ,NULL wipdatasetupid
      ,wipdata.specname
      ,NULL linkid
FROM
(
    SELECT wipdata.containerid
          ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
          ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
          ,wipdata.specid  
          ,wipdata.specname
          ,'WIP Data Collection @'|| SUBSTR(wipdata.specname,0,4) AS "Transaction Type"
          ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatanamename ||': ' , 'break') 
              --- order by row number of inner query
              WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordered_row_number) AS "Details" 
          ,LISTAGG(wipdata.wipdatavalue, 'break') 
              --- order by row number of inner query
             WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ordered_row_number) AS "Values" 
    FROM
    (
      SELECT c.containerid
            ,wldd.wipdatanamename
            ,wldd.wipdatavalue
            ,wldd.iswaferdata
            ,wl.specname
            ,wl.wiplothistoryid
            ,wl.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
            ,wl.specid
            ------- store number of the row in defined order ----------------- 
            , row_number() over (order by c.containername, wldd.servicename) as ordered_row_number
            ------------------------------------------------------------------  
      FROM Container C
      JOIN a_wiplothistory wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
      JOIN a_wiplotdetailshistory wld ON wl.wiplothistoryid = wld.wiplothistoryid
      JOIN a_wiplotdetailsdatahistory wldd ON wld.wiplotdetailshistoryid = wldd.wiplotdetailshistoryid
      WHERE c.containername = :lotID AND wldd.iswaferdata = 0 AND wldd.servicename <> 'AdHocWIPData'
    ) wipdata
    GROUP BY wipdata.containerid
          ,wipdata.wiplothistoryid
          ,wipdata.wiptrackinggroupkeyid
          ,wipdata.specid  
          ,wipdata.specname

) WipData
```

Comment: thanks thinkjet. this is awesome. i also tried a solution close to yours just hours ago using row_number but we have different results. yours is the correct one though. what is the difference between rownum and row_number?

Comment: @GianIsTheName [`ROWNUM`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) is a pseudocolumn which refers to number of the row in selected set. [`row_number()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) is analytical function which applies to set of selected rows. It's possible to get the same result with `row_number()`, just look to updated answer and compare with yours solution.

Comment: I can see our differences in the solution now. On the row_number part, i have only ordered it by containername that is why i am getting incorrect results. thanks alot man.

Answer (score -1):

try to use the stgagg function instead :
[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:15637744429336)

Comment: hello planben, it returns invalid identifier on the stragg

Comment: STRAGG() is simply a user-defined function created before LISTAGG() existed to do the same job. It's less functional and slower and so should never be used when LISTAGG() is available.

Comment: WM_CONCAT() is an undocumented function that's identical to STRAGG()... I don't understand where you're going with this... The OPs question isn't looking for alternatives, there's no need.